# Collect Python output as shell variable

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

I know how to call my python script from my shell script. Please tell me how to collect the output from Python back into the shell script as a variable?

For example, I have a shell script that calls Python from within a while loop. Depending on the value of the Python output, the loop continues or quits.

my.sh

```
x=0
while [ $x -lt 1 ]
do
#Get a value for x from my.py
python ./my.py
done
```

my.py

```
if something: x=1
else: x=0
x
```

As an additional, can I get more than one python output back? i.e., collect values for x & y?

my2.py

```
if something: x,y=1,1
else: x,y=0,0
x
y
```

Comment: Just so you know, the lines `x` and `y` don't actually do anything unless you're in a REPL. If you want those values to be outputted, you need `print` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Same as always.

```
$ foo="$(python -c 'print 42')"
$ echo $foo
42
```

> As an additional, can I get more than one python output back?

No.